# ASP.NET Breakpoints being ignored - have to move binaries

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, debugging

I am using VS2010 and developing a Web Application in ASP.NET with VB code behind. .NET Framework 4.

Since creating a number of build configurations (Debug, Test, PreDel, Live etc) I am now being driven nuts by the fact that every time I do a solution rebuild I have to go to explorer and copy all the build files (dlls, pdbs etc) from their respective build folder (so for the Debug build that is bin\x86\Debug) into the base Bin folder. Otherwise when I run/debug the app all the breakpoints just show the little yellow triangle thing and the app ignores them.

I have done loads or googlising to try and better understand this and from what I can gather the web server (using the dev server not iis) can only find binaries in the root Bin folder and since the new build they will be out of date until I manually copy them over from my config's build folder.

Am I missing something as this seems nonsense to me. The multiple configs are nice for build & deploy etc but it is making debugging a real chore. Having to go to explorer and manually copy files over every time just so the debugger can work is archaic. So I feel sure I must be missing a trick here.

I did think of setting my output path for the Debug config to be the root Bin folder (so the web server will find the latest binaries) but that didnt seem like a good idea and seems risky in that I might end up deploying Debug built binaries.

I am trying to better understand how these all hang together so can someone pls explain what VS is doing and if there is a way to get the latest debug build into a place where the Web server can see them.

Thanks
Mark

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you don't want to go for the fullfledged IIS 7, which could solve your issue. Why dont you try IIS Express to get your issue resolved ?

here is the step by step way to configure.

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/06/28/introducing-iis-express.aspx

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Aby. Superfast response. Looked at the iis Express option. Looks interesting but I cant see explicitly where it helps with the problem of having build binaries in a place where the web server doesnt look. Or am I missing something?